# How to quickly select (inner) line-wise in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation, keymapping

Vim has some very useful text motions such as <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>, etcetera to quickly select a portion of text. But, I often need an inner block in line-wise mode. For example (with line numbers):

```
1:    $foo = array(
2:        'bar' => 'Bar',
3:        'quux' => 'Quux',
4:    );
```

Now, when my cursor is on line 2 or 3 somewhere and I hit <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>, Vim selects line 2, 3 and the indenting spaces on line 4. I just want line 2 and 3. I have tried with <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> but they do the same as with a lowercase <kbd>v</kbd>.

Is there any easy text motion or other quick way to select an inner block in line-wise mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simpler way in the end: [vim-indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) allows me to select regions of text based on the indentation level. This is pretty much the same thing considering my source code is always nicely indented.

Now, if I am on line 2 or 3 in my example, I can simply press <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to select the inner indentation object, and it selects line 2 and 3. Groovy!

Answer (score 4):

I may get downvotes for this, but I'd just do an upward or downward motion the number of lines I need, like <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>  or <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> as long as it's known.

I have a binding that switches between absolute and relative numbering (`:set relativenumber`) so it's visually easy to identify as long as they're all on screen.

Comment: this is the right approach for this specific problem, `relativenumber` helps out a lot, specially if there is a bunch of lines (other than just a couple).

Comment: Thanks for the `relativenumber` setting. I didn't know about that. Unfortunately, I am running Debian Squeeze and it ships with Vim 7.2 which desn't have it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it would be nice to have the behaviour that you describe. If you're determined, then you could always roll your own custom text object using Kana's [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) framework. I used this to create [a text object for working with ruby blocks](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2010/12/a-text-object-for-ruby-blocks/), and found it surprisingly easy to do.

Comment: Custom text objects sound quite useful. Thanks!